# Is it proper way to identify one to many relationship flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Restaurant(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Restaurant'
    menu_restaurant = db.relationship('Menu', backref='Restaurant',cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")


    restaurant_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    restaurant_name = db.Column(db.String(64),nullable=False)
    restaurant_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.user_id"), nullable=False)


    def __init__(self,restaurant_name,restaurant_user_id):
        self.restaurant_name=restaurant_name
        self.restaurant_user_id=restaurant_user_id

class Menu(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'menu'
    item_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
    menu_restaurant_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Restaurant.restaurant_id',ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    item_name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    item_desc = db.Column(db.String(256))
    item_price = db.Column(db.Numeric(10, 2))
    item_image_path = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    

    def __init__(self, menu_restaurant_id, item_name, item_desc,item_price,item_image):
        self.menu_restaurant_id = menu_restaurant_id
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_desc = item_desc
        self.item_price = item_price
        self.item_image = item_image
```

Above the code I want to identify one to many relationship between Restaurant and Menu. One restaurant has many menus but each menu must be related with just one restaurant.If it is not true, I require your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done it in right way.

Is it showing any error when you record data in your Main?

If not, then you have to check whether that Restaurant is having many menus by using for loop in html(jinja templating).
I am assuming that you are familiar with jinja and know to retrieve data from table(and their relationship also)

Just giving you a hint so that you can retrieve all the Menus of that Restaurant.

> ...
>
> ```
> extract_menus = Restaurant.query.filter_by(Restaurant.menu_restaurant).()
> return render_template('xyz.html', extract_menus=extract_menus)
> ```

after this, work on your html template.

I hope I am able give you exact or nearby answer, any suggestion or questions-- you can ask